# Does attending a conference on Sentosa Island allow a visitor to enter without paying the Sentosa Island entrance fee?

Tags: singapore, fees-and-charges, conferences, sentosa-island

[Sentosa island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentosa) has an entrance fee if one enters by ride-sharing app, regular car, taxi, cable ride or monorail. I believe there are some conditions under which one is exempt from this entrance fee. Does attending a conference on Sentosa island qualifies for an entrance fee waiver? Assume that one is staying in a hotel outside Sentosa island.

Comment: The conference may provide access as part of registration, although that probably depends on their contract with the conference venue.

Comment: This might be something worth checking with the conference organisers or the hotel.  On one hand a 2 dollar 'surcharge' doesn't feel like much. On the other hand, it does seem strange to charge someone living there (admittedly rich folks) or at the hotels every time they enter the island

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks, 6 SGD at some time of the day if using Grab  x 1 week = 42 SGD, and maybe actually go back and forth a bit so we're getting close to 100 SGD quick. Agreed, it seems a bit unwelcoming for people who have to work there.

Comment: Ah, looking at the FAQ - basically you remove the cashcard from the unit you use to pay the tolls and get them to scan the QR code if you have a waiver. And *goods* vehicles are exempt. I suspect that there's probably shuttle buses and other waivers if you *work* there.  There's probably a lot not on the FAQ.  The bit that says "I have a QR code... "  on the FAQ everyone has linked is relevant BUT that's something I'm not familiar with as a local. If we're being touristy we take the cable car, and if I'm not I walk in.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible for hotels and events at Sentosa to issue their guests QR codes that grant free entry to Sentosa by car or monorail, see "I have a QR code" in the [Sentosa FAQ](https://www.sentosa.com.sg/en/faqs/).

If you don't have one, you'll have to pay, but it's only $2 off-peak for taxis or $4 combined with the monorail ticket if coming by train.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Does attending a conference on Sentosa island qualifies for an entrance fee waiver?" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: @littleadv Since the only place to.hold conferences in Sentosa is the hotels, they can issue those QR codes to their attendees if they want to.  It depends on the organizer though.

Answer (score 5):

According to the official Sentosa website:

> You can continue to enjoy free island admission by travelling into the island on foot via Sentosa Boardwalk, by cycling, and SBS Transit’s Service 123 (only distance-based bus fare applies). Islander members on either the Insider or Priority tier will enjoy complimentary island admission.

It doesn't look like there are any other allowances.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the relevant part of the FAQ is here

> I have a QR code that allows complimentary island admission. How do I go about using it?
>
> Guests may be issued with a QR code that grants free island admission
> for selected private events and hotel/long term stays within Sentosa.
>
> Instructions for use:
>
> 1. Guests entering the island via the Sentosa Gateway (Personal
>    Vehicle):
>
>    Scan the island admission QR code on the QR reader at the gantry booth. Please be reminded to remove the CashCard from your in-vehicle unit (I.U.) before approaching the Sentosa gantry.
> 2. Guests entering
>    the island via the Sentosa Gateway (Taxi/ Private hire):
>
>    Scan the island admission QR code on the QR reader at the gantry booth. Alternatively, enter via gantry Lane 1 or 2 (far left) at the Sentosa Gateway if you require assistance. Please remind the driver to remove the CashCard from the in-vehicle unit (I.U.) before approaching the Sentosa gantry.
> 3. Guests taking Sentosa Express into the island
>    via VivoCity Station:
>
>    Scan the island admission QR code at the Sentosa Express gate.
>
> Note that the validity period of each QR code varies and will only be
> usable for a limited time. For more information on the QR code issued
> or if you encounter any issues with the QR code (including expired QR
> code), please check with the respective event organiser, hotel or
> business in which you had obtained the QR code from.

You'd need to check with the event organiser or hotel about this and let your driver know *before hand* to avoid any surcharges added to your trip. The system they use to charge is automated and will extract the fee if the road pricing IU unit (also used for parking) has a valid payment card inside.

Answer (score 4):

One is exempt if one arrives by specific methods of transportation, or is a member of the "Islander" membership program. See [here](https://www.sentosa.com.sg/en/faqs/?type=visit-sentosa):

> You can continue to enjoy free island admission by travelling into the island on foot via Sentosa Boardwalk, by cycling, and SBS Transit’s Service 123 (only distance-based bus fare applies). Islander members on either the Insider or Priority tier will enjoy complimentary island admission.